# Windows command line built-in compression/extraction tool?

Tags: command-line-interface, batch-file, compression

I need to write a batch file to unzip files to their current folder from a given root folder.

```
Folder 0
    |----- Folder 1
    |          |----- File1.zip
    |          |----- File2.zip
    |          |----- File3.zip
    |
    |----- Folder 2
    |          |----- File4.zip
    |       
    |----- Folder 3
               |----- File5.zip
               |----- FileN.zip
```

So, I wish that my batch file is launched like so:

```
ocd.bat /d="Folder 0"
```

Then, make it iterate from within the batch file through all of the subfolders to unzip the files exactly where the .zip files are located.

So here's my question:

> **Does the Windows (from XP at least) have a command line for its embedded zip tool? Otherwise, shall I stick to another third-party util?**

Comment: I believe .NET has Zipping assemblies natively, so if powershell is an option for you that might be useful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z72378a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: @jishi: Won't help you much in creating a ZIP file, though. That's just for compressing a stream; you would still have to fit some metadata in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess goes with 7 Zip and its command line tool 7za.exe which I downloaded at: [**`nload 7-Zip for Windows:`**](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

Should you need the command line parameters or some examples of using 7za.exe, please see this link: [**`7-Zip Command-Line Examples`**](http://dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's called `COMPRESS.EXE`

Comment: Shall I consider using it and assume that the users will for usre have it, or using a third-party would be preferable?

Comment: isn't that on the windows isntallation cd for manually compress / decompress those filename.dl_ files?

Comment: It's built into Windows XP, which is what you asked for. Try it, right now, from your command line, and see what it says.

Comment: It says "File not found blah blah blah...". Probably the PATH environment variable not set properly, I guess. Though this brings us to my alternative solution: third-party tool, which was also part of the question. =)

Comment: Balls - I thought it was built into Windows XP, but it's part of the Resource Pack. But, if you're considering bundling a 3rd-party tool, why don't you just bundle compress.exe ?

Comment: I've performed a file-search and I can't find it anywhere. =(

Comment: I know - if you don't have the Resource Kit, it's not on your machine. Download and install the Resource Kit, find the EXE, and bundle that. It's cheaper than buying a 3rd-party tool.

Comment: Will this Resource Kit only works on Windows XP machines and later, or  could it also work on older systems like Windows 2000?

Comment: I have no idea; I'm not going to read the documentation for you at this point. I know that this forum is to have good questions and answers, and "LMGTFY" isn't a great answer, but really - you've been pointed in a certain direction and aren't willing to walk on your own. Why has your compatibility requirement changed from XP+ to 2000+, since yesterday?

You haven't even said what this is for and who the users will be. Is this for a company you work for, or is this for a product you're selling? Are the users/customers tech-savvy, or not?